# How can I create a list/result for each URL in my list?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So, I'm trying to scrape thousands of webpages from a website. That is, one domain name and path, with thousands of parameters. For the example I'm giving below, `'https://A.com'` is my domain name. And I have thousands of parameter as strings in a list, `['a', 'b', 'c']`, for this example. All these pages have the same structure and I want the same parts of the page from all of them. (`link_list.append({'data': j})`, this is the result that I want, which is in the form if a list with each information I extracted from a page being a dictionary in my list)

What I want is, I want my program to return a list for each URL, or in this case, parameter in `mylists`. The following is my code:

```
class ASpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ABC"
    myDom = 'https://A.com/'
    mylists = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    start_urls = []
    
    for mylist in mylists:                   #what I can think of is by using
        start_urls = [myDom + mylist]        #for loop and my start_urls will
                                             #have only one url to run at a
        def parse(self, response):           #time and my link_list list will
            link_list = []                   #return me the result of only
            for xyz in response.css("..."):  #the only single url for this  
                j = xyz.css("...").get()     #iteration and next iteration it
                link_list.append({'data': j})#returns me the next url for the
            print(link_list)                 #parameter in the list
```

What is missing in my code above that I haven't talk about is that, I would like to assign the result, `link_list` from each page to either one master dictionary or list. (If a dictionary, then, the key will be the parameter of the page and value being the result list. If a list, then, first column being parameter of the page and second column being the result list.) The reason I haven't include it in my code is because I'm still struggle on this part and I don't want it to be even more messy.

This above code resulted in the crawler only gave me the result for the last URL in the list.
How can I solve this issue? Thank you very much!

PS: Since there are over 7k pages that I want to scrape, I would also like it to run with smallest amount of time. So, either loop over all the parameters, or all concurrently. However, this is not an issue at the moment.

Comment: Don't use a class, don't even use a method. Just write everything line by line first. Give attention to what each line is doing. If possible use a print statement after each line to double check that it is doing what you want.

Comment: @vishnuprasanth Honestly, I would love to do that. Although, I'm very new to Python and the problem is that I was just following the tutorials on the Scrapy official website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use start_urls as a property. I think this is what you want.

```
class ASpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ABC"
    def __init__(self):
        self.myDom = 'https://A.com/'
        self.mylists = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        self.link_list = dict()


    @property
    def start_urls(self):
        urls = []
        for mylist in self.mylists:
            urls.append(self.myDom + mylist)
        return urls 

    def parse(self, response):
        for xyz in response.css("..."):
            j = xyz.css("...").get()
            self.link_list[j] = j
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. However, I just found out that instead of ``start_urls.append(myDom+mylist)`` it should be ``start_url = [myDom+mylist]``. In this case, I intended to get one ``link_list`` for each URL. Is this possible?

Comment: I see It is really hard to understand what you want. Could you please edit your question with current prints and what you expect when you print

Comment: Thank you very much! I've just edited my post. I don't know if it's more clear, but please let me know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: Did you try to make a dictionary in init with self and append all of the parameters you want.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I do that?